# Gradle Eclipse JSF Project java.lang.ClassNotFoundException javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jsf-2.2, eclipse-wtp

I am using the Gradle plugin in Eclipse to create a JSF project.  I am running the project on Tomcat 9.  When I attempt run on server in Eclipse, I get the **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet** exception.

My gradle.build looks like this:

```
// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Jersey
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.26'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.26'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.26'

    //JAXB
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.26'

    //Javax Servlet
    implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    //JSF
    implementation 'org.glassfish:javax.faces:2.2.16'
}

eclipse {
    wtp {
        facet {
            facet name: "java", version: "1.8"          // Java version
            facet name: "jst.web", version: "3.1"       // Dynamic Web Application
            facet name: "jst.jsf", version: "2.2"       // Java Server Faces
            facet name: "wst.jsdt.web", version: "1.0"  // JavaScript
        }
    }
}

project.webAppDirName='WebContent'
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4" id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>com.xxx</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I can see that gradle has added the correct library to my resources:
[image: Project and External Dependencies]

I cannot think of anything else that could be wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**  If I build a WAR file from the project, and then import that WAR as a new Dynamic Web Project, it runs fine, with no errors.  So, there is obviously some other issue going on here, probably related to Gradle.

**UPDATE2:**
Stack Trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet [Faces Servlet] in web application [/com.foo.bar] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1032)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5075)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
```

Build Path:
[image: Build Path]

Class location:
[image]

Comment: Can you Open Type that class?

Comment: @nitind Yes.  Open Type opens the source for me.

Comment: Doesn't Eclipse already provide the Servlet APIs to develop against *using* Tomcat? Are you supposed to launch using gradle if you have dependencies declared using gradle?

Comment: @nitind.  Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question.  Running the gradle tasks pulls all of the dependencies and also sets up the Eclipse configurations (which facets to use, etc).  Then, to run the server you do Run as --> Run on Server, and run the application normally from the embedded Tomcat server.  I have run a JAX-RS WS doing the same thing, and it works fine, but in this case I am creating a JSF application with a JAX-RS client, and for some reason it cannot find the servlet class.  As far as I can tell the configuration is correct.

Comment: Check the deployed area under your workspace's hidden .metadata directory. You need to make sure the jar with that class is physically there. Did the exception also have a stack trace?

Comment: @nitind Sorry again.  Not sure what I'm looking for there.  I can't find the deployed area under .metadata.  I have added stack trace, build path pointing to jar file, and the jar file location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing "implementation" to "compile" for the required libraries fixed the issue.

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Jersey
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.26'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.26'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.26'

    //JAXB
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.26'

    //Javax Servlet
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

    //JSF
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.faces:2.2.16'

    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.25.1'
}

eclipse {
    wtp {
        facet {

            facets = []
            facet name: "java", version: "1.8"          // Java version
            facet name: "jst.web", version: "3.0"       // Dynamic Web Application
            facet name: "jst.jsf", version: "2.2"       // Java Server Faces
            facet name: "wst.jsdt.web", version: "1.0"  // JavaScript
        }
    }
}

project.webAppDirName='WebContent'
```